# How to check in a css grid if the adjacent cell has a class

Tags: javascript, html, css-grid

I'm trying to create a simple game with html, css and javascript just to practice (I'm learning). I have this grid:

[Grill game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j550E.png)

What I'm trying to achive is when you click on a cell, it turns green but only if an adjacent cell is already green. But if this cell has "death" class then it turns red.

I know I can do it coding manually every cell, like this:

```
b21.addEventListener("click", () => {
if ((b11.classList.contains("green") || b31.classList.contains("green") || 
b22.classList.contains("green")) && !(b21.classList.contains("death")))
    b21.classList.add("green");
else if (b21.classList.contains("death"))
    b21.classList.add("red");
```

})

I'm sure there is a better way to do it. Something more elegant and functional but I don't know how. I need something in that click event that check what classes has the adjacent cell.

Thanks!!

Comment: Assuming no boxes are green/red at the beginning nothing will change if you click on a box, or are you pre-populating boxes with colour at the start?

Comment: Yes! There is always one green at the start

Comment: Give each box a data-id attribute, and then calculate the neighbours. For example, for an 8x8 grid you would need to find boxes -8, +8, -1, +1, and then use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to change the class. But watch out for (literally) the edge cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Create an array of objects in which you define adjacent cells and the cell itself

```
const grid = [
  { 
    adjacentCells: ['b12', 'b21'],
    cell: b11, //DOM element
    id: 'b11',
  },
  {
    adjacentCells: ['b11', 'b13', 'b22'],
    cell: b12,
    id: 'b12',
  },
  ...
]
```

then iterate the array and add eventListener to every DOM element:

```
grid.forEach((element) => {
  element.cell.addEventListener("click", function establishColor() {
    if (this.classList.contains("death")) {
      this.classList.add("red");
    } else {
      element.adjacentCells.forEach((e) => {
        const selectedCell = grid.find((cell) => cell.id === e);
        if (selectedCell && selectedCell.cell.classList.contains("green") && !this.classList.add("green")) {
          this.classList.add("green");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Well acctualy I still have to work on it because you can click the "death" box no matter what. But thanks anyway, that was de logic I was looking for!